# Protobuf Compilation Issues

Tags: python, tensorflow, protoc

I've been trying to run a TensorFlow library and in order to do that I have to compile Protobuf libraries. I'm using the following command:

```
C:\tensorflow-master\tensorflow\models>protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
```

The following error comes up:

```
'protoc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

operable program or batch file.

I'm not sure what the issue is here. I'm running it out of the TensorFlow models directory, but it's still not recognizing protoc.

Comment: Hi!  You need the protoc binary.  I see it's mentioned here https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/4f32535fe7040bb1e429ad0e3c948a492a89482d/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md#installation, but I think you need to install it separately.   Does this https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/README.md#c-installation---windows help?

Comment: Check this Video- https://youtu.be/COlbP62-B-U?t=368

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the Protocols buffer library first.

pip install from your command line as shown below:

```
pip install protobuf
```

Then run your protoc command again

Comment: hi i have installed protobuf separately but it still giving me same error as above