# Cannot find `protoc` command

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, protoc

When I run this:

```
protoc --python_out=. .\object_detection\protos\anchor_generator.proto
```

on a tensorflow object detection file on the command line, I get:

```
'protoc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I followed all instructions in [protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46491112/protoc-object-detection-protos-proto-no-such-file-or-directory), but they never worked for me

In addition to the searches I made, I tried this command:

```
py-3.6 -m pip install protobuf
```

and it works for me.

I typed  the command again

```
python_out=. .\object_detection\protos\anchor_generator.proto
```

But it still fails and this:

```
C:\Users\laptop market\Downloads\bin\protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --py_out=.
```

also fails.

Comment: Change title and reformat text.

Comment: protoc is a separate program that drives compiling protobuf files in all languages. You can get it here: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protobuf Compilation Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46084375/protobuf-compilation-issues)

Answer (score 10):

You need to save the `protoc.exe` file which is located in the zip file to  `C:\Users\Satyarth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts`.

Replace "Satyarth" from the path with your username.

If it still isn't working, put the above path in the environment variables.

Answer (score 10):

The way I solved the issue on Windows 10  was to

1. copy the protoc file https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v3.12.4/protoc-3.12.4-win64.zip from the link https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases
2. Extract the contents of the zip file.
3. Bin directory contains the protoc.exe
4. Update the environment variable to point to the bin directory that contains the protoc.exe
5. Re-Open the cmd as the environment variable take effect only on new command window
6. run **protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.**

Answer (score 3):

Go to this page to find the downloadable files for the latest version of Protobuf: https://www.github.com/google/protobuf/releases/latest

Then, just download the zip file beginning with `protoc` for your OS.

Next, extract it, and you will get a `protoc` application.

Finally, you can place it on your local machine.

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure that you have protobuf >=3 installed on your system.

On Windos protobuf is usually installed through your Python package
manager, e.g. conda or pip, and should already be in your environment.
You can check if it is installed with either `conda list` or
`pip freeze`.

If it is not installed, simply run

`conda install protobuf`
or
`pip install protobuf`

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered this error a while ago
To go around this: **Follow the steps listed below:**

1. Install the protoc which is applicable for your operating system from this [github repo](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.13.0) for me it was
   `protoc-3.13.0-win64.zip`
2. Extract the zip file and put it in a folder where it will be permanently there
3. Go to the *bin* folder present in the protocFolder in my case I had to go to
   **F:\Programing_stuff\ML\protoc-3.17.3-win64\bin** or just find where the `protoc.exe` file is and copy the path
4. Then in the windows search bar type `path` and click on `Edit the system environment variables`
5. And the path of the bin folder

Hope this helps, If doesn't check this [video](https://youtu.be/dZh_ps8gKgs?t=904)
Or this [website](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-install-tensorflow-2-object-detection-api-on-windows-2eef9b7ae869) (If you want to install TensorFlow)

Answer (score 2):

My solution for windows:

- Download protoc-3.18.0-win64.zip from [here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases)
- Extract zip and Copy proto.exe from bin directory and paste it in models/research folder
- Then run this command `protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.`

Answer (score 1):

1. when you download the `.zip` from https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases, make sure you're getting the correct file for your OS.
2. for Windows, in environment variables, you need to add the folder that contains `protoc.exe`, so in my case `C:\Program Files\GoogleProtobuf\bin`

That got it working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your platform, you might have to install protobuf locally. See [the docs](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md#manual-protobuf-compiler-installation-and-usage) for more detailed instructions.

Comment: my windows is 10,64 bit .which platform  do you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all consider installing `Protobuf Compiler` inside the *C:\Program Files* folder. Then you need to compile `protobuf` every time you want to use Tensorflow Object Detection API. To do this, open **cmd** in the `../models/research` directory and run

`“C:\Program Files\protoc-<PROTO_VERSION>\bin\protoc.exe” object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.`

where `<PROTO_VERSION>` is the version of protobuf compiler, you're using (for example `protoc-3.5.1-win64` or the name of the folder you've picked for the protobuf).

Be advised, that you should compile protobuf in the every **cmd** window that is launched to work with Object Detection.

Comment: when I saved  protobuf compiler zip folder in a path c:\program files ,it appears a text message "you don't have permission to save in this location contact the administrator to obtain permission".

Comment: windows is 10 64 bit ,and i installed protoc-3.5.1-win32.

Comment: try to extract your zip folder into `Program files` using the permission of an administrator

Comment: this command appears "C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." after using a permission of administrator and  typing this command "C:\Program Files\protoc-protoc-3.6.1-win32\bin\protoc.exe” object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=." in c:\tensorflow\models\research

Comment: did you put you path into quotational marks such like `"C:\Program Files\..."` instead of writing just `C:\Program Files\...` ?

Comment: definitely yes because the path contains a spaces . i tried 10 times

Comment: @m.mera Did you try downloading the `protoc-3.5.1-win64` instead since you have 64-bit Windows?