# "protoc" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file Windows

Tags: command-prompt

I am trying to compile a library into a particular folder by executing the command:

```
"protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=."
```

inside the folder.

In the command prompt, within the exact location I want to call the command, I am receiving an error :

```
"C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\TFLibraries/protoc is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."
```

My input is:

```
"C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\TFLibraries/protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=."
```

Now I know this considered a very basic question but I am a beginner and I don't have a good understanding of an OS or command prompts. The error occurs whenever there is a space in the command line. Now I have seen many people indicate going into your system properties and editing your system variables, but I don't understand editing a new path will fix this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find \`protoc\` command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52929161/cannot-find-protoc-command)

Answer (score 2):

I think that this because that you did not setup the system environment. You should add the bin folder which is in the protoc folder to the path in the system environment. i.e.

[image]

Comment: Recommended solution

Answer (score 1):

if you are using conda env then paste:

`protoc-3.17.3-win64/bin/protoc into  the C:/Users/NEERAJ/anaconda3/`

Answer (score -4):

Guys Just rebooting can solve your problem.